# Selecting (subsetting) by multi index in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, subset, dataframe

I was wondering if there is a clean way of selecting or subsetting a Pandas dataframe based on multi index. My data looks like this (id and date are index):

```
                        values                  
id     date
10113  2010-07-21      24.7000
       2010-07-22      25.2600  
       2010-07-23      25.2800  
       2010-07-26      25.3700 
       2010-07-27      25.2900 
10223  2011-07-21      24.7000
       2011-07-22      25.2600  
       2011-07-23      25.2800  
       2011-07-26      25.3700 
       2011-07-27      25.2900
```

I want something like this:

```
df.xs[10223).xs('2011-07-21':'2011-07-30')
```

but above code doesn't work for the second `xs()`. `xs()` can only select a single row, not a subset of dataframe. I also tried `df.query()` and `df.ix()`, but no luck.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should be able to use `.xs` or `.ix` in the following way:

```
print df.ix[(10223,'2011-07-21'):(10223,'2011-07-30')]

                 values
id    date              
10223 2011-07-21   24.70
      2011-07-22   25.26
      2011-07-23   25.28
      2011-07-26   25.37
      2011-07-27   25.29

print df.xs(10223,level='id')

            values
date              
2011-07-21   24.70
2011-07-22   25.26
2011-07-23   25.28
2011-07-26   25.37
2011-07-27   25.29
```

See [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#hierarchical-indexing-multiindex) for more information

Comment: Thanks. First one gives me what I wanted. But second doesn't. Because I only showed a part of data id=10223 have a time series beyond '2011-07-27', I have to slice the date as well.